# DataSourceUpdateMode equivalent WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In Windows forms we have the option to set the binding of a control to a property, and then set the DataSourceUpdateMode to OnPropertyChanged.

How can this be achieved in WPF?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to DataSourceUpdateMode in WPF is `UpdateSourceTrigger`.